# Euclidean norm second derivative

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, differential

I really need Your help.

I need to prove that Euclidean norm is strictly convex. I know that a function is strictly convex if $f ''(x)>0$. Can I use it for Euclidean norm and how? $||x||''=\frac{||x||^2-x^2}{||x||^3}$

Thank You!

Comment: It's difficult to show something is strictly convex when it is not.

Comment: Your expression for the Hessian is incorrect; indeed it is ill-posed. $x^2$ does not make sense for a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function 
$$
\lVert \mbox{ }\rVert:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R},\, f(x)=\lVert x\rVert
$$
is certainly convex. In fact, given $t\in [0,1]$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have:
$$
\lVert tx+(1-t)y\rVert=\lVert tx+(1-t)y\rVert\le \lVert tx\rVert+\lVert (1-t)y\rVert=t\lVert x\rVert+(1-t)\lVert y\rVert.
$$
But is it ***STRICTLY CONVEX***? i.e. if $t\in (0,1)$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with $x\ne y$, then
$$
\lVert tx+(1-t)y\rVert<t\Vert x\rVert+(1-t)\lVert y\rVert.
$$
The answer is ***NO***. In fact, if $t\in (0,1)$, and $y=sx$, with $0<s \ne 1$,  and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we certainly have $x\ne y$. But
\begin{eqnarray}
\lVert tx+(1-t)y\rVert&=&\lVert tx+(1-t)sx\rVert=\lVert (t+(1-t)s)x\rVert=(t+(1-t)s)\lVert x\rVert\\
&=&t\lVert x\rVert+(1-t)\lVert sx\rVert=t\lVert x\rVert+(1-t)\lVert y\rVert
\end{eqnarray}
Hence the function $\lVert\mbox{ } \rVert$ is ***CONVEX*** but ***NOT STRICTLY CONVEX***.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a second-derivative proof for $\mathbb{R}^n$. The gradient and Hessian do not exist at the origin, but everywhere else they are given by
$$\nabla f(x) = \|x\|^{-1} x, \quad \nabla^2 f(x) = \|x\|^{-1} I - \|x\|^{-3} xx^T$$
Strict convexity requires that the Hessian be positive definite; that is, $v^T(\nabla^2 f(x))v>0$ for all $v\neq 0$. But suppose $v=\alpha x$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar. Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\nabla^2 f(x) \cdot v &= \alpha \left( \|x\|^{-1} I - \|x\|^{-3} xx^T \right) x \\
&= \alpha \|x\|^{-1} x - \alpha \|x\|^{-3} (xx^T) x = \alpha \|x\|^{-1} x - \alpha \|x\|^{-3} x (x^T x) \\
&= \alpha\|x\|^{-1} x - \alpha\|x\|^{-3} \|x\|^2 x = \alpha\|x\|^{-1} x - \alpha\|x\|^{-1}x = 0.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus $v^T (\nabla^2 f(x) ) v = 0$, and the Hessian is not positive definite as required. This establishes that the norm is not strictly convex anywhere other than the origin. It's not strictly convex at the origin, either, but one must appeal to the fundamental definition for that instead, as Mercy offered. (That answer should be the one accepted, not this one, because it is complete.)

Comment: The penultimate term of the last line is missing an `x`.  Tried to just edit to this effect but the edit was rejected/ :/

Comment: @MattPhillips thank you! fixed

Comment: Actually could you explain your use of the transpose in this answer?  Where does that come from exactly and why is the term in your answer $(xx^T)$ rather than $(x^Tx)$ (which would produce quite a different result!)?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to work with the definition that a function f is convex if for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$ and for all $x,y \in (a,b)$:
$$ f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) \leq (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda f(y)$$

Then:

$$ ||(1-\lambda x) + \lambda y ||^2 = \sum_{i} |(1-\lambda x_i) + \lambda y_i|^2 \leq  \sum_{i} (1-\lambda) |x_i|^2 + \lambda |y_i|^2 = (1-\lambda)||x||^2 + \lambda ||y||^2 $$

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm really looking for the derivative version.

Answer (score -1):

By the [definition of convexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) and the triangle inequality we have

> $$ ||ax+(1-a)y|| \leq |a| ||x||+ |1-a|||y||,\quad 0\leq a\leq1. $$

Comment: Can't it be done with a second derivative?

Comment: You just proved that the norm is a convex function, not a STRICTLY CONVEX FUNCTION.

Comment: Would you care expaining what's the downvote for? It is the first answer to be posted.

Comment: My guess is that it fails to answer the question. The OP is asking about strict convexity; this establishes only convexity. And even so, it only reproduces the definition of convexity, and doesn't actually show the steps taken to get there. Of course the norm is not, in fact, strictly convex, and the only good answer to this question knowledges that!

Comment: @MichaelGrant: this answer tells him what kind of conevixity the norm has with a proof.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Actually, no. Strict convexity implies convexity, but not the reverse. By demonstrating just convexity, without addressing strict convexity at all, you did not answer the question. In contrast, Mercy's answer definitively proves that the norm is not strictly convex.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: As I said "my answer tells what kind of property the norm has". How can you say that it does not answer the question? I think you are missing the point!

Comment: The poster asked about strict convexity. You responded that the norm is convex---something the poster in all likelihood *already knows*. You said nothing whatsoever, positively or negatively, about strict convexity. I am not the one missing the point.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: You can understand my answer the way you like but as I said "it tells what kind of convexity the norm has with a proof "

Comment: And you can continue to feel persecuted if you like. Your proof is not, in fact, a complete proof, and it does not address the poster's question. Mercy's is the best answer here, and I am clearly not the only one to think so. You're lucky yours has only one down vote. Time for you to simmer down.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Talking about downvoting is it the goal to down vote the answers on this website? I do not think this is a useful comment! As I said you can think whatever you want about this answer and who's answers is the best! I am not here for this! The problem wih many people is that "they see things in one way".